# Enter each line user inputs with file. functions

Tags: python, function, user-input

```
n = int(input('How many tracks are in the album?: ')) 
for i in range(n): 
    line = raw_input('Next Track: ') 
    lines.append(line)
```

Where it says line = raw_input('Next Track: ') is where the text would be saved to the file. But, if there are, say, 20, how would you make it so each track is recorded and saved?

Here is the code where the text gets written:

```
f.write("Track Name/Rating: " + line +"\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your `write()` function should be inside the `for` loop. Appending line to `lines` list is not neccessary then. You just write every `line` "on fly" to the file.
Remember to define `f` before with `"w"` parameter and to add `f.close` or your `line` will get stuck in a buffer.

Here is a working piece of code:

```
n = int(input('How many tracks are in the album?: '))


f=open("directory","w")

for i in range(n):

    line = raw_input('Next Track: ') 
    f.write("Track Name/Rating: " + line +"\n")
f.close()
```